# Spring Reactive Rest Controller: Issue with application/json Content Type Instead of text/event-stream - No Encoder Found for Content Type Null

Tags: rest, kotlin, controller, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to create a reactive REST controller in my Spring Boot application that returns responses as `application/json` content type objects without using the `.block()` method. However, when I make a request to the endpoint, I receive the following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No Encoder for [reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.example.demo.Potato>] with preset Content-Type 'null'
```

**Tech stack**

- Kotin 1.8.22
- Java 17.0.7 LTS (Amazon Corretto 17.0.7.7.1 (build 17.0.7+7-LTS))
- Spring Boot 3.1.2-SNAPSHOT
- Spring Boot-starter-webflux 3.1.1
- Jackson module kotlin 2.15.2
- Jackson Core 2.15.2
- Jackson Databind 2.15.2

**Sample code**

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

@SpringBootApplication class DemoApplication
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@RestController
class DemoController {
    @GetMapping(
            "demo-get",
            consumes = [MediaType.ALL_VALUE],
            produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
    )
    suspend fun getDemo(): ResponseEntity<Mono<Potato>> =
            ResponseEntity.ok(Mono.just(Potato(test = "IamJustAtest")))
}

data class Potato(val test: String)
```

As shown in the sample code, the `DemoController` returns a `Mono<Potato>` in the response body. However, when making a request to the `/demo-get` endpoint, the application throws the mentioned `HttpMessageNotWritableException`.

How can I properly configure my reactive REST controller to return the response as `application/json` content type without using the `.block()` method and avoid this exception? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

1. I tried to use a `.block()` method and it helped, but then code started to work slower and it breaks the reactive concept.
2. I tried to remove a `produce` attribute in the `GetMapping` annotation, but the `Content Type` of the response was changed to `text/event-stream`. If I try to consume this endpoint with a standard HTTP client, it can't read it as `application/json`.
3. Tried to set `producer` attribute as `application/json; charset=UTF-8`, but it also didn't help.
4. Tried to add 'Accept': 'application/json' in header, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you try to remove "ResponseEntity" wrapper ? Instead, just return `Mono<Potato>` directly. Also, try to avoid mixing different versions of Spring Boot. You use a nightly version of Spring Boot with a release version of Webflux. They should be aligned, to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I removed `ResponseEntity` and aligned Spring versions (to v3.1.1). However, I still have the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Do not return a `Mono` or `Flux` from a *suspendable* function.
Both technologies are different ways to manage async/non-blocking workloads. Using them both in method signature is redundant.

Your example works when removing the `suspend` keyword from your `demoGet` function. Then, it returns the right json object:

```json
{"test":"IamJustAtest"}
```

Note that the inverse is also true. You can keep the `suspend` as long as you do not return a reactor `Publisher` (Mono, Flux) object:

```kotlin
@RestController
class DemoController {
    @GetMapping("demo-get", produces = ["application/json"])
    suspend fun getDemo(): Potato = Potato(test = "IamJustAtest")
}
```

### Mixing reactor and coroutines

Now, it *is* possible to mix coroutines with reactive-streams in internal code.
For that, jetbrains provide a dedicated library: `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor` (*note: if you've created your project through [spring initializer](https://start.spring.io/), it should already be imported in your project).

Spring official documentation has a [dedicated section about it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/languages/kotlin/coroutines.html#how-reactive-translates-to-coroutines).

We can adapt your sample to test it:

#### Example 1: consume Mono from suspendable function

1. Imagine your potato object is now acquired through a third-party component using reactor component (that we'll simplify as a first-order function here) :

   ```kotlin
   fun getPotato() = Mono.just(Potato("supplied via reactor"))
   ```
2. If you want to make your HTTP endpoint suspendable, you can use `Mono<T>.awaitSingle() : T` extension function to unwrap Mono result in a coroutine context:

   ```kotlin
   @RestController
   class DemoController {
       @GetMapping("demo-get", produces = ["application/json"])
       suspend fun getDemo(): Potato = getPotato().awaitSingle()
   }
   ```

This will properly return:

```json
{"test":"supplied via reactor"}
```

#### Example 2: convert coroutine to Mono object

Inversely, if you've got a coroutine-based component returning a result, you can transform it to a Mono object via the `mono {}` function. Therefore, you transform a coroutine (suspendable function) to a reactive pipeline, usable from non-suspendable function:

```kotlin
suspend fun getPotato() = Potato("supplied via coroutine")

@RestController
class DemoController {
    @GetMapping("demo-get", produces = ["application/json"])
    fun getDemo(): Mono<Potato> = mono { getPotato() }
}
```